# what is the simplest way to pop up an instruction from ruby code in windows?

Tags: ruby

The platform is windows xp x86.

I want to write a function, like `pop_up_instruction()`, when call it, there should be a popup dialog or notepad or command-line or whatever else to print a block of instruction on it.

the instruction contains "\r\n", like such:

```
Explorer [/n] [/e] [(,)/root,<object>] [/select,<object>]

/n                Opens a new single-pane window for the default
                  selection. This is usually the root of the drive Windows
                   is installed on. If the window is already open, a
                  duplicate opens.
/e                Opens Windows Explorer in its default view.
/root,<object>    Opens a window view of the specified object.
/select,<object>  Opens a window view with the specified folder, file or
                  application selected.
```

I wrote a function to convert the above string into a vb-string, and print it to a vbs file and call this vbs file using system(the_vbs_file), the_vbs_file content:

```
  MsgBox "Explorer [/n] [/e] [(,)/root,<object>] [/select,<object>]" & vbCrLf & _
  "" & vbCrLf & _
  "/n                Opens a new single-pane window for the default" & vbCrLf & _
  "                  selection. This is usually the root of the drive Windows" & vbCrLf & _
  "                   is installed on. If the window is already open, a" & vbCrLf & _
  "                  duplicate opens." & vbCrLf & _
  "/e                Opens Windows Explorer in its default view." & vbCrLf & _
  "/root,<object>    Opens a window view of the specified object." & vbCrLf & _
  "/select,<object>  Opens a window view with the specified folder, file or" & vbCrLf & _
  "                  application selected." & vbCrLf & _
  ""
```

Do we have other better way?

Comment: furthermore, is it possible to popup some window that we can select text and copy on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at win32api:

```
require "Win32API"  
title, message =  'dialog title', "line 1\nline 2"
Win32API.new('user32','MessageBox',['L', 'P', 'P', 'L'],'I').call(0,message,title,0)
```